# Is it possible to remove panel2 from SplitContainer in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form with a SplitContainer. I need to hide/remove the panel2 from this container and  I want the panel1 to occupy the entire form. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel2.aspx

It is not possible to remove it.

You can, however, hide it:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();
```

Answer (score 18):

Set property [`Panel2Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel2collapsed.aspx) to true:

```
splitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```

Comment: @Jyina This is the correct answer. Hiding `Panel2` does not make `Panel1` occupy the entire form.